# Integrity constraint violation PDO method (create query) php

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, many-to-many

I have 3 tables which is subcategory, product, and prod_category.

When I create my product, if it successful, it will return the successfull product_id, after that it will capture the form subcategory column ,to carry out the next query which insert product_id and subcategory_id to the prod_category table. I tested out in a single php file to test the whether the function is working. It can insert, but when I fit into my situation, it was giving me this error.

> Warning: PDOStatement::execute() [pdostatement.execute]: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`yokotachi`.`prod_category`, CONSTRAINT `prod_category_ibfk_4` FOREIGN KEY (`product_id`) REFERENCES `product` (`product_id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE) in C:\xampp\htdocs\yokotachi\models\Prod_category.php on line 27

I confirm that, 2 parameter was passed into the function, but i dont know why it cannot perform the query.

```
if($_POST){ 
$title = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['title']);
$model = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['model']);
$description = stripslashes($_POST['description']);
$feature = stripslashes($_POST['feature']);
$specification = stripslashes($_POST['specification']); 

$subcategory_name = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['product_subcategory']);

$sub_obj = $subcategory->find_by_sub_category_name($subcategory_name);

$subcategory_id = $sub_obj->sub_category_id;
echo $subcategory_id;
$executed_product_id=
    $product->create($title,$model,$description,$feature,$specification);
echo "im here".$subcategory_id;
echo $executed_product_id;
$responde = $prod_category->create($executed_product_id,$subcategory_id);
if($responde){
    echo "<script>";
    echo "alert(".$executed_product_id.");";
    echo "</script>";
    header("location: ../../../views/admin/product/product_index.php");
}}
```

i did saw 1 post is reindex problem, and asked to truncate the table. But I have no idea , how to perform the truncate query in my situation.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you the one who set up the database tables or is it someone else's work?

Comment: @N.B.: I'd say someone else set the tables up. To the OP: read up on _[FOREIGN KEY CONSTRAINTS](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-foreign-key-constraints.html)_ and, just to avoid having to do 3 separate query's: _[JOIN](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html)_, too.

Comment: line 27 is    if(!$stmt->execute()){throw new PDOException()}

Comment: @N.B nope, i'm setting up the table myself...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message seems to be telling you that the product ID number you're trying to use in the table "prod_category" doesn't exist in the table "product".

You need to find out what value $executed_product_id has after this line executes.

```
$executed_product_id=
    $product->create($title,$model,$description,$feature,$specification);
```

If the value it has isn't in the table "product", then that's your problem. The foreign key reference requires that product ID to exist in "product" before you can use it in "prod_category".

Comment: Oic, but actually the executed_product_id is the product_id that was returned when carry out
    $product>create($title,$model,$description,$feature,$specification);

i tried to echo before carry out the query,and the there is a value that already exist. Even in the function to carry out, after the prepare statement and before the execution of the query, i tried to echo it out and it do have the value that I want. So,i have no idea,how can it be like that :(

Comment: What did you try to echo? PHP variables? If so, look at the actual table instead.

Comment: yup, how says look at the actual table? what do you mean? you mean when executing create, is it the product_id is exist or created?

Comment: I mean use the mysql command-line tool or something like phpMyAdmin to connect to the database, and look directly at the contents of the table. See whether the values that you expect to be there are actually there. They're probably not.

Comment: hmm, oic...yupz,actually i did tried that too.. I did tried to insert my expected data by using phpMyadmin,it success.. >.< how come ..

Comment: If you can insert the expected data manually, but you can't insert it with code, then your code is wrong. I'd look at the code in $product->create(...) first.

Comment: erm...probably..but i tested out with individual function before using the function for my process, and it can insert, when I creating for a product, then afterward i have to get the product_id for the newly created product and carry out my next function which is insert to prod_cateogry table, then it occurs that error, I did check the params until it go into the function, it show me expected value which I want to insert,but the query cannot be executed.